# Saving data using SQL Server in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering if Visual Studio comes with SQL database? or do I have to install SQL server additionally in order to use it with Visual Studio?

I need it to store and manipulate data from textboxes and other controls in WinForms.

Comment: This really depends on what you mean by "use it with visual studio" and how your environment is setup.  For example if you already have sql server installed somewhere you can use it w/o having to install it again on your local box.

Answer (score 1):

The VS2010 installer gives you the option of installing SQL Server 2008 Express Edition.. This edition is good enough for development purposes but is not intended for production use to be honest..

I guess it depends how serious you're going with it, you should definitely install the "full" SQL Server Development Edition if it's gonna be some serious database dev.